# Prove that $a_n$ is a perfect square if $n$ is even without generating functions or Taylor series.

Tags: recursion, catalan-numbers

Let $a_n$ be the number of positive integers whose digits are all $1$, $3$, or $4$, and add up to $n$.

For example, $a_5 = 6$, since there are six integers with the desired property: $41, 14, 311, 131, 113$, and $11111$.

Prove that $a_n$ is a perfect square if $n$ is even.

I did some experimentation with small cases and found the recurrence relation $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-4}$. How should I continue?

Also, I'd prefer a solution that does not use generating functions or the Taylor series.

Comment: From that recurrence one can find a closed form of a_n.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The number of positive integers whose digits are all $1$, $3$, or $4$, and add up to $2k$, is a perfect square](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904587/the-number-of-positive-integers-whose-digits-are-all-1-3-or-4-and-add-u)

Comment: yeah, that's pretty much this question, but is there a solution without generating functions and taylor series?
edit: thanks MJD

Comment: Then can you add that specifically to your question? "Prove this without generating functions" isn't a duplicate, but "Prove this" is.

Comment: ok I fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks. I'd include that in the question text as well, but you have distinguished it from the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to observe numerically that $a_{2n} = F_n^2$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. That motivates looking for a bijection between the integers counted by $a_n$ and ordered pairs of Fibonacci numbers.

It's also well-known that $F_n$ counts partitions of an $n\times 1$ rectangle into $1\times1$ squares and $2\times1$ rectangles. For example, $F_4=5$ because:

[image: F_5]

So $F_n^2$ counts partitions of an $n\times2$ rectangle into the same pieces. For example, $F_3^2=9$ because:

[image: F_3^2]

For each such diagram, draw a zigzag line starting from upper left, going S then NE then S then NE ... until ending at the bottom right:

[image: F_3^2 with zigzags]

Now break the zigzag into pieces as much as possible while having each $2\times1$ rectangle lie all in the same piece:

[image: breaking up those zigzags]

Finally, reading the lengths of the pieces in order along each zigzag results in the integers counted by $a_n$:

$\displaystyle \begin{matrix} 111111&1113&1311\\1131&114&141\\3111&33&411 \end{matrix}$

Comment: Another way of seeing this same bijection: $F_n$ counts the number of length-$n$ bit strings starting with $0$ with no two consecutive $1$s (the $1$s mark the ends of the $1\times2$ squares); similarly, $a_{2n}$ counts the number of length-$2n$ bit strings starting with $0$ where the $1$s come in runs of exactly $2$ or $3$. Given ordered pairs of the former, interlace them and then place an additional $1$ in front of each existing $1$ (if there's a $1$ already there, don't change it). This is a bijection. Example in next comment:

Comment: For $n=3$, the ordered pairs $(000,000)$, $(000,001)$, $(000,010)$, $(001,000)$, $(001,001)$, $(001,010)$, $(010,000)$, $(010,001)$, and $(010,010)$ interlace to $000000$, $000001$, $000100$, $000010$, $000011$, $000110$, $001000$, $001001$, and $001100$, which after adding the extra $1$s become, respectively, $000000$, $000011$, $001100$, $000110$, $000111$, $001110$, $011000$, $011011$, and $011100$. This is the same bijection as above; the examples are listed in the same order even.